# How to get raw HTTP header string in Node.js with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently work with Node.js and express.js. For my current project I need to access the raw strings of the HTTP headers (charset and accepted).

There is a function in express.js which returns those charsets and accepted headers, however, these are sorted by quality and therefore not useable for me in this special case I need.

```
req.accepted // Returns sorted array of accepted header

req.acceptedCharsets // Returns sorted array of accepted lang header
```

However, I need the raw strings (`iso-8859-5;q=.2, unicode-1-1;q=0.8, text/*;q=.5, application/json`).

Now is there a way how I can access those raw strings in my express app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

req.headers

as in

```
    var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.headers);
    res.header('time', 12345);

    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.listen(3000)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const headersJson = JSON.stringify(req.headers)
  console.log(headersJson)

  // Save into file using fs module

  // save into database

  next()
})
```